# AIR Native Extension for accessing native UI controls on IOS

Tags: air, static-libraries, adt, air-native-extension

Does anyone have a clear idea about or a sample of air native extension that helps me use alert view of apple touch devices.
I tried a lot for the same but ended up getting no success.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not tried this library anyhow please try with [NativeAlert](http://www.as3gamegears.com/air-native-extension/nativealert/).

(OR)

This for alternative for access native UI.

You can try with [ios-theme-for-flex-mobile-projects](http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/2011/06/ios-theme-for-flex-mobile-projects-proof-of-concept.html) link.

This link shows like iOS Alert view.

Please find `mobiletheme_ios_usage.fxp` link you can download that project then workout.You can see iOS alert view(Not Native UI).

Comment: The first option was pretty helpfull, as the second one doesnot not use the native UI.
Thanx @Raja